# How to commit a snapshot on esxi 3.5

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a question. Basically i want to extend the partition of a windows server. I have read that before extending a partition have to commit all the snapshots which in my case is only one!

The question is: Deleting the snapshot means commit the data to the disk? I will not loose nothing on my operating system?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in VMware parlance, deleting the snapshot commits all changes since the snapshot was created.